# Remove weekends Silverlight DatePicker

Tags: c#, silverlight, datepicker

I have a little question about Silverlight's datepicker.

I wonder if someone knows how to remove every week end from silverlight's datepicker?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: you want to blackout dates?

Comment: Yes exactly. But dates will be bind using the MVVM pattern. So I wonder how blackout every week end. Thanks for your answer by the way

Answer (score 0):

Its going to be a lot of coding,

Simple way is by specifying the weekend dates,

```
<Calendar Name="calWorkingDays" SelectionMode="SingleDate">
    <Calendar.BlackoutDates>
        <CalendarDateRange Start="8/6/14" End="8/7/14"/>
        <CalendarDateRange Start="8/20/14" End="8/20/14"/>
        <CalendarDateRange Start="8/28/14" End="8/30/14"/>
    </Calendar.BlackoutDates>
</Calendar>
```

If you are doing it using MVVM, have a Service method to get the BlackoutDates and bind as mentioned here. [datepicker-with-holiday-blackouts-and-tooltips](http://sachabarbs.wordpress.com/2013/11/25/wpf-datepicker-with-holiday-blackouts-and-tooltips/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I don't know how many weekends I have to blackout so I think your solution doesn't work in my case.